# Xamarin Studio Licensing Issues

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

Xamarin is free now right ? but my Xamarin account is still at the 'paid' business level until it runs out - fine - whatever.

However, I work disconnected from the internet quite often, and an incredibly annoying thing has started happening - Xamarin has been refusing to build my projects because it has been unable to verify my account. It does it several times a day, and I have to try and find some way of getting an internet connection in order to build my apps.

I could log out of my Xamarin account, and Xamarin Studio reverts to the 'community' edition, but then I cant use components etc.

Does anyone know why this is suddenly happening, and why Xamarin would refuse to build software even though the tools are free - whether you have a business account or not.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded Xamarin studio from their website and installed it. After installation I got a Xamarin Studio (old) and a new one. The new one did not had this problem.